# Select Calendar Date and Update Link Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, calendar

I have a Link Label on my page. When I click on the label a calendar pops up. When I click on a date on the calendar I want my link label to update to that particular date in this format '30 JAN 2017'

The issue is because of the local variable `var dateText =...`, My label never updates but gets the correct format.

If I comment or remove the date formatting section than my label updates to the correct date but does not contain the format I'm looking for.

How do I update my link label with the desired formatting when clicking on a specific date on the calendar?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#dp").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

      var dateText = new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', {
        day: 'numeric',
        month: 'short',
        year: 'numeric'
      }).split(' ').join(' ');

      $("#datep").html(dateText);
    },
    beforeShow: function(event, ui) {
      var $link = $("#datep");
      ui.dpDiv.offset({
        top: $link.offset().top + 10,
        left: $link.offset().left + 10
      });
    }
  });

  $("#datep").click(function() {
    $("#dp").datepicker("show");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="datep">Date Picker Link Label</a>
<input type="hidden" id="dp" />
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `new Date().toLocaleString(...`, which uses the current date. All you're missing is passing the `dateText` parameter to the Date constructor:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#dp").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

      var dateText = new Date(dateText).toLocaleString('en-GB', {
        day: 'numeric',
        month: 'short',
        year: 'numeric'
      }).split(' ').join(' ');

      $("#datep").html(dateText);
    },
    beforeShow: function(event, ui) {
      var $link = $("#datep");
      ui.dpDiv.offset({
        top: $link.offset().top + 10,
        left: $link.offset().left + 10
      });
    }
  });

  $("#datep").click(function() {
    $("#dp").datepicker("show");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="datep">Date Picker Link Label</a>
<input type="hidden" id="dp" />
<div></div>
```